# Open new terminal tab and execute script

Tags: terminal, applescript, osascript

I need to merge two osascript scripts, so that with one command I can open a new terminal tab and execute a script like `echo hello` into that new tab.

This one opens a new terminal tab.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
```

This one opens a new window and runs `echo hello`

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" do script "echo hello" end tell'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is by using "ttab"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab

Just run `ttab 'ls -la'` here `ls -la` is the command that I want to execute in a new tab.

Note: `ttab` needs the installation of NPM

Comment: `ttab` is a node package which calls a bash script which calls osascript. It’s a needlessly convoluted solution to control the Terminal on macOS.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know any better way to make a new tab, but you can run a command in the frontmost tab or window with `do script "" in window 1`.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    repeat while contents of selected tab of window 1 starts with linefeed
        delay 0.01
    end repeat
    do script "echo a" in window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way besides using the do script command? Want to run command using Hyper Terminal which doesn't support that syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet we use. I would suggest:

- Put this into a function, like one called "tab"
- for the command use a variable that you pass into the function

  ```
  osascript 
      -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to activate" \
          -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"t\" using {command down}" \
          -e "do script \"echo hello\" in front window" \
      -e "end tell"
      > /dev/null
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [adayzdone's answer](/a/466654/892801), but slightly different:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' \
  -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}' \
  -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello" in front window'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello" in tab 2 of window 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

- To open new terminal if not any terminal exists
- if terminal exists, open a new tab
- Don't forget to change "your script" (x2) sections

```bash
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    if not (exists window 1) then
        do script "your script"
        do script "your script2"
    else
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
        repeat while contents of selected tab of window 1 starts with linefeed
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        do script "your script" in window 1
        do script "your script2" in window 1
    end if
end tell
```

ref: https://superuser.com/a/466650/1046035

Answer (score 0):

on top of [Lri's answer](https://superuser.com/a/466650/1243883), if you want to use terminal while the script is running in the background,

change window 1 to window 2:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    repeat while contents of selected tab of window 2 starts with linefeed
        delay 0.01
    end repeat
    do script "echo a" in window 2
end tell
```